# как удалить дубликат

Tags: git

> ```
> $ git fsck
> ```
>
> Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
>   error in tree 849b7c6b65eadca8ecf0f9454aba33988da8c4e0: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
>   error in tree 90895e50331f4e6ef7ef114435c543addf17394d: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
>   Checking objects: 100% (115298/115298), done.

Comment: Что означает "подозреваемая на дубликат"? Дубликат чего?

Comment: И не совсем понятно, причём тут git.

Comment: Вы что имеете в виду? Два одинаковых репозитория? Две папки с абсолютно одинаковым содержимым внутри одного репозитория?

Comment: мне заказчики еще сложнее объясняют, а разве не понятно что папка и есть дубликат вероятно

Comment: @DzmitriySalodki наверное, заказчики вам деньги платят за то, что вы угадываете их мысли. А тут как минимум 7 человек прочитали и не поняли ваш вопрос. Расскажите подробнее. Вот Arhad хорошие вопросы задал.

Comment: Вы рейтинг зарабатываете, я должен понимать то что вы мне втюхиваете, супер программы, сверхнадежные, быстрые, дешевые. как пишет программа так я и пишу.

Comment: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13178720/4827341), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10931954/4827341)